# How to subtract time from current time in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi  want to subtract 1 min from current time  in my sql i used following query but it is showing null

query

```
SELECT curtime() - INTERVAL '00:00:30' SECOND
```

what should i do to get my result

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For minute you can do so

```
SELECT curtime() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
```

Another one will be something like below but its return type will string no time

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
,' ',-1)
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/45134)

Comment: could umake me  please  make me understand why we wrote -1

Comment: @bablisharma not sure if thats a bug for later versions or not but for Mysql 5.6 it works [`See Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d41d8/938)

Comment: @bablisharma when you add/subtract date/time using interval you need to specify the number with format like `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` to add day ,`+ INTERVAL 1 MONTH` to add one month and same for year,week hour..

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 SELECT TIMEDIFF(curtime(),'00:00:30');
```

**In Seconds**

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(curtime(),'00:00:30'));
```

Or Static One

```
   SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('00:01:00','00:00:30'))
```

Comment: @bablisharma i am getting  60448

Comment: @bablisharma result of above query

Comment: @bablisharma With static current time SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('00:01:00','00:00:30')); it will give 30 sec. try this one

Comment: i want  using curtime

Comment: Have already done check above first query  SELECT TIMEDIFF(curtime(),'00:00:30');

Comment: i used this but this is showing  time in different  way

Comment: how you want to display ?

Comment: i want  to display in time following format 00:00:00

Comment: it gives the same : I have just tried it gives--> 19:03:43